# Change vscode C++ library path

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, configuration

Currently, I want to practice my C++ so I open a new folder to write some C++ codes. But weird thing happened. The editor shows me that one library bits/stdc++.h can not be resolved. Initially, I tried to delete and download MingW again at the D panel and reset the system path. But after that nothing changed.

I tracked the path of iostream (this one could be resolved) but found somehow my vscode point the library path at C->MicroSoft Visual Studio->2019....->iostream instead of D:/MingW/bin. I don't know how to solve this. So I tried running a cpp file at cmd that outputs "Hello World" to check my g++ setting, and it ran smoothly. I guess this is because my Vscode sets its library-finding path to the Microsoft VS 2019 but I can't find out where to change this.

Below will attach some screenshots as a detailed description, hope they can help you fix this question.
[image]

Note that I do not have the c_cpp_properties.json file, I also don't know why I don't have.
[image]

Now I want to set my editor library-finding path to D:/MingW/bin. Or if my assumption is wrong, please point out the correct way.

Comment: You probably need to change your tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json

Comment: `bits/stdc++.h` you should never include this file: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Start by getting rid of [stdc++.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Then we can talk. Code including a compiler specific header is not worth spending time on. And *please* don't post images. Post everything relevant as *text*.

Answer (score 0):

Change the header file to something wrong like "issotream". When it highlights it as an error, hover over it and select quick fix and click IncludePath. This will open a settings page, there you can add your bin path.

Answer (score 0):

Open settings (UI if you're not comfortable with json), you can do it pressing

```
ctrl + shift + P
```

then select **Preferences: Open Settings (UI)** and search for **include path**. From the left drop down menu select **Extensions -> C/C++** and navigate to **Include Path**. Here you can add new default paths.

Mind you that this will not tell the compiler anything about the libraries.